# Command Click in Sublime Text 3 like RubyMine

Tags: sublimetext3, rubymine

Is there a plugin for Sublime Text 3 that allows you to do the Cmd + click on a variable/function to find other occurrences/calls/declarations of said variable/function? This is a feature in RubyMine that I really love but want to break away from using something paid since my trial is going to expire.

Comment: Just FYI, extended use of Sublime requires a license as well. The only difference is that Sublime doesn't have a limited trial time like RubyMine. And while you're at it, you *really* should be using [Sublime Text 3](http://sublimetext.com/3) instead of v2, which is quite old and has a lot of bugs and missing features.

Comment: I misspoke earlier. I am on SublimeText3 and I do have a license, which is a hell of a lot cheaper than pay 150+ per year for rubyMine.

Comment: This is not nearly as out-of-the-box or snazzy, but you can use [starscope](https://github.com/eapache/starscope) to generate ctags/cscope files and then use the [Cscope Sublime plugin](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Cscope).  It'd be nice if the process could be simplified and automated, but not sure if that's possible with a Sublime plugin.

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler if you want to go the ctags route, you can use the [CTags](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/CTags) plugin. All you need is the correct `ctags` binary on your system, and it works semi-automagically to get things set up properly. But, see my answer below for the easiest solution.

Answer (score 0):

For Ruby (and other languages that aren't Python*****) I'd suggest taking a look at [**`SublimeCodeIntel`**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeCodeIntel), available via [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io), like most Sublime plugins. It will require some manual setup and some back-end time to index Ruby's standard library and any gems/extras you have installed, but once that's done it tends to work fairly well. It includes Jump to Symbol Definition (defaults to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-click, sorry), among other features, including intelligent auto-completion. I have the following set in my user preferences to facilitate that:

```js
"auto_complete_triggers":
[
    {
        "characters": "|",
        "selector": "source.ruby"
    },
    {
        "characters": ".",
        "selector": "source, text.html"
    }
]
```

***** If you use Python, [**`Anaconda`**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Anaconda) (no relation whatsoever to the Anaconda Python distribution) is much superior to SublimeCodeIntel, at least in my experience. It's ready to go almost immediately (no lengthy indexing required) and is loaded with features, including several linters, so you don't need a separate [linting plugin](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SublimeLinter). I love it. (And no, I'm not the author, or even a major contributor).